# Can we get the list of followed edges of the current edge?

Tags: sumo

In SUMO, can we get the list of next edges (if there exits) given the current edge? Also, can we get the four incoming approaches to an normal intersection?

Comment: If we can know which node the vehicle is in, we can query all links of the intersection. Then the list would consist of four outgoing edges of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to use TraCI and need the following edge on the route of a specific vehicle or if you just want a static network analysis. For the latter you can use sumolib (at least if you can use python):

```
 # import the library
 import sumolib
 # parse the net
 net = sumolib.net.readNet('myNet.net.xml')
 # retrieve the successor edges of an edge
 nextEdges = net.getEdge('myEdgeID').getOutgoing()
 # retrieve the incoming edges of the destination of an edge
 nextEdges = net.getEdge('myEdgeID').getToNode().getIncoming()
```

see https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Sumolib.html

Comment: Thanks Michael. Actually I want to force vehicles to turn randomly at intersections when I control the traffic signal using TraCI. My idea is to update the current route of the first vehicle in every approaching lane to [ current edge, next edge, next next edge]. I think I need the 'next next edge' in case vehicles disapper after reach the 'next edge'. Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: This was the default behavior in very early versions of sumo but currently the vehicles drive the final edge up to the end (unless you specify an arrivalPos)